# XBox One Controller Periodically Disconnects

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

My Xbox One has been working great for about a year. In the past week, the controller has started disconnecting every five or ten minutes. It takes about 20 seconds to reconnect. This happens with two different controllers in multiple games. The controller batteries are good.

Nothing has recently changed with my setup. I'm on a couch about eight feet directly in front of the Kinect. It has a clear line of sight.

Any theories on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you got any other battery packs you could test out? It's possible the clip on the one you are using might be giving out

Comment: My batteries on both controllers are fresh AAs. No rechargeables involved.

Comment: @user96909 Try swapping them anyway, with a batch from a different pack, in case they were old from the shop?  The behaviour sounds like my 360 when the controllers' batteries are running out...

Comment: Related thread on the Xbox forums: [...controller is disconnecting all the time!](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/4677/t/1825293.aspx)

Comment: Updated the controller?

Comment: Try holding the power button on the Xbox until it boots off completly

Answer (score 1):

When Microsoft releases firmware updates, these updates occasionally include improvements for your controllers. Unlike the Xbox One updates, which are applied automatically, controllers need to be updated manually. Headsets too are often updated so keep them plugged into the controller while you update. Here's a paragraph from the Microsoft Xbox One website about the controller update procedure. Follow this and see if it solves your problem:

> To download the update, connect a controller to your Xbox One with a
>   USB cable. Keep any headsets connected to the controller. Connect to
>   Xbox Live. Press the Menu. Go to Settings > Devices & accessories and
>   select the controller. If you have multiple controllers attached, you
>   can select Buzz – which will cause the selected controller to vibrate.
>   Then select Update to download the new firmware to the controller
>   attached via the USB cable, and the screen will show the “Updating
>   controller…” progress screen. When you see the “Controller updated”
>   screen, press B to go back to the Devices & accessories main page.
>   Reselect the controller.